# NameError: name 'setupterm' is not defined??? How can I solve it?

Tags: random, import, curses, terminfo

NameError: name 'setupterm' is not defined ??

How can I solve it?

File "c:\Users", line 5, in 
screen=curses.initscr()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

`setupterm` is one of several [terminfo](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html) (low-level) functions. PDCurses implements none of those, as noted in its [`HISTORY.md`](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/blob/master/docs/HISTORY.md) file:

> - Eliminated term.h and terminfo.c, and moved mvcur() to move.c. These stub functions, done on request (with others then requesting that I take them away -- can't win), were a misguided attempt to facilitate using PDCurses with certain non-C languages -- which, apparently, they didn't end up actually doing. They're also, regrettably, specified as part of the X/Open curses standard, even though they in effect describe an entirely different interface layer (one on which traditional curses, but not PDCurses, is built).

That note was added for [PDCurses 3.7](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/commit/4235c02ae9e0cbe191c9744e8985b076618b2d51), at the end of 2018.  Earlier versions had a non-functional stub file.